# TypeScript: Is it possible to pass an instance of an interface into a react component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I have a component i want to show on login:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Localization from '../Modules/Localization';
import ILanguageChangedObservor from '../Interfaces/ILanguageChangedObservor';

class Login extends React.Component {

  private observor : ILanguageChangedObservor;

  constructor(languageObservor : ILanguageChangedObservor) {
    super();
    this.observor = languageObservor;
  }

  public currentLanguage : Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings(navigator.language.split('-')[0].toString());

  public changeBrowserLanguage(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    this.currentLanguage = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings(event.currentTarget.value);
    this.forceUpdate();
  }

  render() {

    var englishStrings = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings("en");
    var germanStrings = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings("de");
    var frenchStrings = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings("de");
    var spanishStrings = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings("es");

    return (
        <div>
                <p>
                <select onChange={ e => this.changeBrowserLanguage(e) }>
                  <option value="en">{englishStrings.languageInNative}</option>
                  <option value="de">{germanStrings.languageInNative}</option>
                  <option value="fr">{frenchStrings.languageInNative}</option>
                  <option value="es">{spanishStrings.languageInNative}</option>
                </select>
                </p>
                {this.currentLanguage.welcome}<br />
        </div>
    );

  }
}

export default Login;
```

What i want to do is when the language is set on login, tell the observor which will be the parent page:

Parent screen:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Login from './Screens/Login';
import * as Localization from './Modules/Localization';
import ILanguageChangedObservor from './Interfaces/ILanguageChangedObservor';

const logo = require('./logo.svg');

class App extends React.Component implements ILanguageChangedObservor {

  public update(toLanguage : Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings) {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h2>Welcome to React</h2>
        </div>
        <Login />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting that i could pass the instance of the parent into the login component, something like this:

```
<Login languageObservor=this />
```

But it appears this is not an available option. Is it possible to atleast pass a callback function into a component? Im new to react so still trying to work out limitations. Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You *can* pass callbacks defined in the Parent to the child Login for it to call when it ascertains the user's chosen language.

Something like:

```
class App extends React.Component implements ILanguageChangedObservor {

  public update(toLanguage : Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings) {
    //Do what needs to be done when language is change in Login
  }

  render() {
    <Login callMeWhenYouGetLang={ this.update } />
  }
}



class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  public changeBrowserLanguage(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) {
    this.currentLanguage = new Localization.Localization.LocalizedStrings(event.currentTarget.value);
    // vvvvvvvvv
    this.props.callMeWhenYouGetLang(this.currentLanguage);
    // ^^^^^^^^
    this.forceUpdate();

  }
}
```

With React, passing whole instances of Component classes or even their accompanying DOM nodes into children Components is a **big no-no**. The main reason being that you really don't want to get into situations where something changes on your Component, and you can't figure out why because there's no direct line-of-action *on the Component itself*.

You also should look into [learning Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/CoreConcepts.html) to help direct your app's state in a way that will be more manageable when your app grows in complexity. Your Login component could ascertain the user's language, change the app's global state, which would then be fed down throughout the entire application. This would prevent you having to worry about parent callbacks or passing down the language to each and every component.

One final thing... you've been spelling `Observer` wrong. :)